BigQuery JSON results return DateTime values as objects with a "value" property
When I execute a simple query against BigQuery using the @google-cloud/bigquery npm package, any columns that are of type DateTime are returned as objects with "value" properties, like this...
{
    "id": "B4BCEEB7-BB95-4163-8B22-C81588682AEC",
    "aString": "37SBAUL4464",
    "effectiveDate": {
        "value": "1970-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
}

This is a nuisance. Is there any way to disable this behavior or get DateTime properties to simply return their values without mangling the output format?
The desired format would simply be as follows - the lack of random object insertions for values...
{
    "id": "B4BCEEB7-BB95-4163-8B22-C81588682AEC",
    "aString": "37SBAUL4464",
    "effectiveDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00"
}

Here are the relevant portions of my code...
import {BigQuery} from '@google-cloud/bigquery'; // at the top of the file

const bigQueryClient = new BigQuery();
const query = `
    select
        p.PolicyID as id,
        p.SomeString as aString,
        p.EffectiveDate as effectiveDate
    from
        `my-dataset-11111.2222222222__001.Policy` as p
`;

const options = {
    query: query,
    location: config.bigQueryLocation,
};

const [rows] = await bigQueryClient.query(options);


This is a default way of BigQuery Node.js library handles certain data types like DateTime which are returned as special wrapper objects. There isn’t actually a direct flag to disable this wrapping in the BigQuery client library. I think the best approach that you can do is to create a function to recursively traverse the results objects and unwrap the values.
import {BigQuery} from '@google-cloud/bigquery';

// ... (your existing code)

function unwrapBigQueryResults(rows) {
    return rows.map(row => {
        const newRow = {};
        for (const key in row) {
            if (row[key] && typeof row[key] === 'object' && 'value' in row[key]) {
                newRow[key] = row[key].value;
            } else if (Array.isArray(row[key])) { 
                newRow[key] = row[key].map(item => unwrapBigQueryResults([item])[0]); 
            } else {
                newRow[key] = row[key];
            }
        }
        return newRow;
    });
}

const [rows] = await bigQueryClient.query(options);
const unwrappedRows = unwrapBigQueryResults(rows);
console.log(unwrappedRows); 

